# How to backup/restore specific apps for factory reset?

Tags: backup, factory-reset, restore

I have a Nexus 7 2013 and now with Android 5.0 I would like to get rid of all the try and error I made with my first tablet through a factory reset.

I want to backup and restore most of my apps but not all. So I can't make a full backup, I must be able to select which apps to backup (and later restore).

Do you know any app or tutorial backup a selection of apps from your Android (without root please)?

I just don't want to loose my games' progress and apps' preferences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though you don't want to make a full backup, you might still wish to take a look at [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/16575) to get an idea what is possible. That page also mentions some helpers for your issue:

- [Simple Backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/37687/16575) runs from your computer and, as the screenshots indicate, can also be used to backup a single app (so you could use it for each app you want to backup)
- [Helium Backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/37738/16575) (formerly known as *Carbon Backup*) is an app you can install to your device. Select the apps you want to backup, start the process – and it creates a separate backup file for each app. Which means, you can restore them separately/selectively.
- It's also possible to do this [via the command-line](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/57603/16575), which might be a little non-intuitive.
- Not on that page, but making the latter a little more easy: [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) is a tool I wrote (and am still on it – it's far from being complete yet). It creates you scripts for backup/restore (where you simply can comment-out/remove those apps you don't wish to take care for), plus more. Possible drawback: *Adebar* is written for [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)), so you will need an OS that has this (Linux, and possibly also Mac should do).

There's one thing all those have in common: they require ADB-tools to be available. For that part, you can take a look at [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575) to avoid installing too much with too much hassle ;)

---

**EDIT: WARNING!**

If you find another app promising easy backups without requiring root or ADB, **be aware it might leave your apps' data out!** To my knowledge, before Android 4.0 only root-apps were able to backup app data, and with 4.0 only the option via ADB became available. Make sure to read the description of such an app *very carefully*.

To pick an example (experience of the OP, sadly): There's an app called [App Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.appbackup). On a quick view it sounds like a perfect match. But looking deeper into the description you will find:

> App Backup cannot backup data or settings of apps for you, but it only backup the apk files.

Which means: It only cares for the apps themselves (which you always could re-install from their respective sources anyway – with the added work of looking them all up separately, and maybe some of them disappeared, or are no longer available in a specific version you might want for some reason – so this app still has a good reason to exist), but doesn't cover their data.

Comment: Thx Izzy. Meanwhile I found [App Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.appbackup) that enables me to select every app (even system apps) I want to backup and doesn't require root or ADB. Backups are exported as .apk files. Seems legit?

Comment: Almost – if you don't want the app's data. `.apk` usually is just the app without data. From the app's description: *App Backup cannot backup data or settings of apps for you, but it only backup the apk files.* So you'll lose your settings and all data entered into the app, including game levels etc., unless backed-up otherwise.

Comment: oh sh!t... too late. thx anyway

Comment: If it had been that easy, I hadn't left that option out of my answer. But I should have left a warning – my bad, sorry. Will edit that in, might save somebody else a lot of trouble.

Comment: I would upvote it again if I could :P Thanks again Izzy, it was really my fault, I'm an Android noob and I was trying to avoid rooting the device, so that application was really tempting :P

Comment: Understandable – but "lesson learned" I'd say: Always read the full description, especially in cases where your data is depending on it. I'm sorry you had to learn that "the hard way" – that's the trouble if one is "used to" something (to me the difference was clear). Well, past is gone – next time both of us know better :)

Answer (score 0):

Without root it's impossible, the quickest way is to root your device and use titanium backup.

Comment: Not quite correct (see my answer). Though I won't say anything against TiBu :)